# <unknown client> for <unknown server>, Cannot decrypt ticket

Tags: sssd, freeipa

After reinstalling FreeIPA server and client(s), one client refuses to authenticate.

$ ipa user-find
properly list users

I can kinit user successfully.

ipa server krb5krc.log

```
krb5kdc[4425](info): AS_REQ (8 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), DEPRECATED:des3-cbc-sha1(16), DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac(23), camellia128-cts-cmac(25), camellia256-cts-cmac(26)}) 10.0.1.8: NEEDED_PREAUTH: myuser@MYDOMAIN.COM for krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.COM@MYDOMAIN.COM, Additional pre-authentication required
krb5kdc[4425](info): closing down fd 11
krb5kdc[4427](info): AS_REQ (8 etypes {aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96(18), aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96(17), aes256-cts-hmac-sha384-192(20), aes128-cts-hmac-sha256-128(19), DEPRECATED:des3-cbc-sha1(16), DEPRECATED:arcfour-hmac(23), camellia128-cts-cmac(25), camellia256-cts-cmac(26)}) 10.0.1.8: FIND_FAST: <unknown client> for <unknown server>, Cannot decrypt ticket for krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.COM@MYDOMAIN.COM using keytab key for krbtgt/MYDOMAIN.COM@MYDOMAIN.COM while handling ap-request armor
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that cleaning sssd cache fixes the issue:

```
$ systemctl stop sssd
$ rm -f /var/lib/sss/db/*
$ systemctl start sssd
```

Answer (score 0):

Bless you, I was having the same problem.  Two freeipa servers replicating on AlmaLinux 8.  Spun up a new AlmaLinux 8 test VM and enrolled it with no issues.  Tried sshing to it with my newly created user, and no joy.  Just get prompted for a password again.  /var/log/messages on the test VM showed the same message.  Clearing the sssd cache did the trick.